# Redirect to other domain except one subdirectory which needs to be redirected to a subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect a domain to other domain. However, one subfolder needs to be redirected to a subdomain. For example:

- `http://old.com/archives/` -> `http://new.com/archives/`
- `http://old.com/blog/archives/123` -> `http://blog.new.com/archives/123`

I added the following in `.htaccess` under the root folder of the old domain:

```
#Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/blog/(.*)$ http://blog.new.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://new.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It works for all URLs except the subdomain `blog`.

For most URLs with the subdomain `blog`, it redirects to `http://new.com/`.

In this case, how can I edit it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ http://blog.new.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://new.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Because htaccess `RewriteRule` left url does not begin with `/`

Comment: Read the error logs. It's not a 500 error just because I deleted one / that was not necessary

Comment: Sorry. I confirm that your solution works. (I don't know why I got a 500 error.) Thanks for your help.